# HOW to change preview?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, intellij-idea

I have been editing the stupid android studio layout for the last 3 hours, and I cant change the preview!

[image: Preview selection menu]

For some reason, android studio layout is stuck on **wear square!** I just want my layout to be a Nexus 6p, but when I click on that, instead of changing the layout editor phone, **it just jumps to my layout-normal xml!**

How can I change the phone shown on the layout editor? It is causing me way too much trouble

Comment: I think the problem is all the various `res/layout` folders you have.

Comment: did you try to clean or rebuild project? you can also go to file-clear cache and restart

Comment: what version of AS are you using? could be a bug in the version. Try after updating the IDE.

Answer (score 5):

You can change the devices by pressing D from the keyboard into the Preview pane. Previous settings will be set to default when you will restart the studio.

Answer (score 2):

Resize your layout by dragging the bottom-right corner of your layout to the far bottom right of your screen.
The "Device in Editor" drop-down will change to "Custom".
You should now be able to select any listed device.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. Accidentally pressed "Force Refresh Layout" from the design toolbar (where you select design and blueprint) and it fixed the problem.

Answer (score -2):

You might have made a different layout folder for watch and other screen resolution for device like layout, layout-large, layout-xlarge.
Try to check for your layout folder by cleaning and rebuilding project again.